# Is there any function which will reduce the size of my query in using "CASE"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to fetch and display monthly data in one report , currently i'm using CASE function the fetch the value based on month. Is there any other function which will make my query more optimized

```sql
select MONTH(sale_date) AS MOIST,CASE WHEN MONTH(sale_date) = 1  THEN A 
                                      WHEN MONTH(sale_date) = 2 THEN B 
                                      WHEN MONTH(sale_date) = 3 THEN C
                                      WHEN MONTH(sale_date) = 4 THEN  D 
                                      else E 
                                 END as value
```

Is there any why to make still simple and optimized

Comment: What is `A`, `B`, `C` ... are those columns?

Comment: know lets assume that as value

Answer (score 3):

You can use the alternative syntax for `case`:

```
select MONTH(sale_date) AS MOIST,
       (CASE MONTH(sale_date)
            WHEN 1 THEN A 
            WHEN 2 THEN B 
            WHEN 3 THEN C
            WHEN 4 THEN D 
            ELSE E 
        END) as value
```

You could also use a `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select month(sale_date),
       coalesce(v.val, E)
from . . . outer apply
     (select val
      from (values (1, A), (2, B), (3, C), (4, D)
           ) v(mon, val)
      where v.mon = month(sale_date)
     ) v
```

Or `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select month(sale_date),
       coalesce(v.val, E)
from . . . left join
     (values (1, A), (2, B), (3, C), (4, D)
     ) v(mon, val)
     on v.mon = month(sale_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', then:

```
select MONTH(sale_date) AS MOIST,CASE WHEN MONTH(sale_date) <= 4  THEN CHAR(MONTH(sale_date) + 64) 
                                      else E 
                                 END as value
```

If the values are something else and you can find out some handy pattern as above, then use it. If not, then implement a stored function which gets 1, 2, 3 or 4 as parameter and returns the correct value, like:

```
select MONTH(sale_date) AS MOIST,CASE WHEN MONTH(sale_date) <= 1  THEN myFunction(sale_date) 
                                      else E 
                                 END as value
```

or even:

```
select MONTH(sale_date) AS MOIST,myFunction(sale_date) as value
```

Comment: just for example i made it as A,B,C,D but it was a sales amount and it was not constant value

Comment: I will run this in sql server, so have i will define a function??

Comment: @Angel yes, my answer only dealt with that as a possibility. However, if you do not have such a pattern, you can use a stored function where this issue is handled, yet, you see only the function in your query, which makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @Angel Here you can see useful information about creating and using a stored function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Angel you are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.